# Why for loop can hold returned boolean value but not primitive boolean value?

Tags: java, for-loop, boolean

Take a look at the **for loop of the** following code snippet.

```
class Practice
{ 
    static boolean foo(char c){
        System.out.print(c); 
        return true; 
    } 
    public static void main( String[] args ){
        int i = 0; 
        for (foo('A'); foo('B') && (i < 2); foo('C')){
            i++; 
            foo('D'); 
        } 
    } 
}
```

**This part of code does not gives error when compiled and executed. Even though it is getting a boolean value from the function**

```
for (foo('A'); foo('B') && (i < 2); foo('C')){
     i++; 
     foo('D'); 
}
```

**Whereas this is an error,**

```
boolean b = true;

for (b;some_condition;b){

    //statements

}

// or,

for (true;some_condition;true){

    //statements

}
```

Comment: Lets say you have code like `boolean b = true; b; true;`. What would you expect `b;` or `true;` to achieve? It does nothing/it doesn't affect anything - which is why it is considered as programmer's mistake (just like dead code) and compiler will inform us about it. With `foo(..)` there is a possibility of some change in state of application.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just to expand a little on [Jahan's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/67047678/3788176):

`ForInit` and `ForUpdate` have to be `StatementExpressions`.

A `StatementExpression` is an expression that can be made into a statement (specifically, imaginatively, `StatementExpression ;` is called an *`ExpressionStatement`*).

Not all expressions are `StatementExpressions`: for example, you can't write this:

```
boolean b = true;
b;  // b is an expression, not a StatementExpression
```

This is sort of like shouting a word, "true!" - it has no meaning in and of itself: you have to surround it with some context, like "it is true that Java has 4 letters".

Similarly, `4 + 3;` isn't allowed, because it doesn't "do" anything: 7 just... is.

However, you can write this:

```
someMethod(b); // MethodInvocation is a StatementExpression
```

So, you can use `someMethod(b)` in the `ForInit` and `ForUpdate`, but you can't use `b`.

You can find all of the different kinds of `StatementExpression` [in the language spec](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se14/html/jls-14.html#jls-StatementExpression) (examples are mine):

```
StatementExpression:
  Assignment                         // b = true
  PreIncrementExpression             // ++i
  PreDecrementExpression             // --i
  PostIncrementExpression            // i++
  PostDecrementExpression            // i--
  MethodInvocation                   // someMethod(b)
  ClassInstanceCreationExpression    // new Object()
```

Answer (score 4):

This is the java official grammar from Oracle:

```
ForControl:
    ForVarControl
    ForInit ; [Expression] ; [ForUpdate]

ForVarControl:
    {VariableModifier} Type VariableDeclaratorId  ForVarControlRest

ForVarControlRest:
    ForVariableDeclaratorsRest ; [Expression] ; [ForUpdate]
    : Expression

ForVariableDeclaratorsRest:
    [= VariableInitializer] { , VariableDeclarator }

ForInit: 
ForUpdate:
    StatementExpression { , StatementExpression }
```

As I understand ForInit and ForUpdate expect a statement, not a literal value like `true` or an expression like `b`.

https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-18.html